# Why is my fstab entry for an external USB drive not working?

Tags: arch-linux, mount, automounting, external-hdd, fstab

I have an external USB drive which my system recognizes as `/dev/sdb1`. I want to have it automounted with 755 permissions on boot and shared over the network with samba. I created the mount point `/mnt/mybook` for it, and I've mounted it manually with no problems. If I do `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/mybook`, it mounts correctly and I can access the contents.

I figured this would be simple enough, so I read up on *fstab* and came up with the following line for it:

```
UUID=C252-9CA3 /mnt/mybook vfat defaults,mode=755 0 0
```

I got the UUID from blkid.

When I reboot, the drive is not automounted, much less with the 755 permissions I want. How can I make it so the drive gets correctly automounted with the desired permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try an alternate approach, which is to recognize your device at the [udev](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev) level and use `/dev/mybook-partition` in `/etc/fstab`. Put something like the following in `/etc/udev/rules.d/dwilliams.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid %N", RESULT=="C252-9CA3", SYMLINK+="mybook-partition"
```

The section on [Auto mounting USB devices in the Arch wiki for udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Auto_mounting_USB_devices) might help you further.

Comment: This is better since you might possibly boot the system without the drive attached and if I remember correctly you get dumped in to single-user mode.